# How to prevent anyone pushing multiple commits at once in github?

Tags: git, github

Can I prevent my collaborators from pushing more than one commit at once on github in my repo? I'd also like to do the same in PRs, e.g. the checks should fail if the PR contains more than one commits. However, everything goes in normal flow if there is exactly one commit.

Comment: You might be able to write a custom server-hook?

Comment: Why?! This seems to go against best practises, and I can’t see what problem multiple commits would cause.

Comment: It seems a very strange thing to block, why would you want to do this?

Comment: I use pull based strategy in my jenkins. In new commits, I don't have any way to determine the number of commits pushed after last build. So, if every collaborator is pushing only one commit, I can easily access everything changed after last build.

Comment: Why do you need to know how many commits after last build?

Comment: Don’t most CI systems provide a variable with the last built commit? IMHO it’d be better to try to compute the difference than enforce this, again IMHO, bad rule. An [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), if you will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first step will be to mark the branches you care about as [protected branches](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-protected-branches), so that they can only be committed to via Pull Requests, not direct pushes.

You could then build the check you describe using the flow for [a CI server](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/building-a-ci-server), with the only actual check being [to retrieve the list of commits](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#list-commits-on-a-pull-request) and count them.

However, if what you're trying to achieve is a "clean" history (I disagree that that's a good thing, but some people like it), the more common solution is to [enforce a squash merge](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/configuring-commit-squashing-for-pull-requests) on the Pull Request. That way, regardless of how your contributors prepare their work, [you end up with a single commit at the end](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-request-merges#squash-and-merge-your-pull-request-commits).

If what you're actually looking for is for each *build* on your CI server to have only one new commit, that seems like an X/Y Problem: your CI server shouldn't *need* to make that kind of assumption, it should be tracking the builds itself.